# Can I update Visual Studio Community 2015 RC to 2015 Release when the final version is released, (without reinstallation)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I know it's not a big deal to reinstall, but the file is more than 4 GB large; and the installation process is time consuming. When the final VS 2015 is released, can I update from RC version without reinstalling from scratch?

Comment: Related: How to upgrade Visual Studio 2015 RC to RTM (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527901/how-to-upgrade-visual-studio-2015-rc-to-rtm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[That is the plan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/04/29/build-2015-news-visual-studio-code-visual-studio-2015-rc-team-foundation-server-2015-rc-visual-studio-2013-update-5.aspx), but being pre-release software, anything can happen.

> **Upgrade to RTM.** Upgrading from RC to the final release (“RTM”) of Visual Studio and TFS 2015 should be smooth.

Comment: it's not. Some third party tools doesn't get 'updated' and creates  some errors. I found ripple to stop working had to uninstall/install.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, this is a supported upgrade path and we test for it. You may also have other version of Visual Studio installed, side by side installs are also tested for (VS 2013 side by side with VS 2015 is officially supported).

That being said VS 2015 does bring in a number of external components so there's always a risk that on some configuration the upgrade will not work properly.

Source: I'm working on the Visual Studio team.

Comment: I can confirm, all working, and freed up a lot of disk space :D

Comment: Whats the process? Just running the Release installer?

Comment: @Pantelis. Yes, just run the installer. The installer knows how to clean the official non-RTM versions.

Comment: Alright, this messed up Xamarin and the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage package. There are a couple messageboxes showing on startup mentioning the packages in question fail to load.

Comment: This practically set VS useless. I'm running a repair, fingers crossed. Great work guys...

Comment: @Pantelis, you were using pre-release software. You should have expected issues.

Comment: @Pantelis Xamarin is a third-party product, but you *should* post the specific error. As for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage, google it and you'll see that you probably need to clear the version-specific ComonentModelCache, ie `%LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`, as shown eg [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c1b2d94-5338-47c0-b148-0cf46b4a47d5/microsoftvisualstudioeditorimplementationeditorpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already did that, did not work. The error was rather cryptic and nothing came up on google. I've uninstalled and installed again and still had the same issue. I eventually deleted everything from %AppData% Roaming and Local and Program Files (x86) regarding Visual Studio (dunno how safe this might be) and installing again for the third time as we speak.

Comment: @Pantelis not safe *at all*. You wrecked the installation. Removing, installing, deleting without a specific reason simply makes things worse. You should post a separate question for this, including the exact errors *and anything found in the setup and error logs*

Comment: I deleted those folders after uninstall. Anyway, depending on the results of the last installation effort, my last resort is to do a Windows reset.

Comment: Back to a working VS! The folders deletion messed DevExpress controls, which I'd update anyway to the latest release

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's necessary to remove the previous versions of Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable x64 and x86 to permit the upgrade to complete.  This involves a full restart.