# How to upgrade Visual Studio 2015 RC to RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2015

According to the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152154/can-i-update-visual-studio-community-2015-rc-to-2015-release-when-the-final-vers) question, upgrading from RC to RTM is a supported and tested upgrade path. Now that VS 2015 RTM is out I want to do exactly that. However, I can't find out the interface menu to do it.

How do I upgrade Visual Studio Community 2015 RC to the RTM version?

Comment: Related: Can I update Visual Studio Community 2015 RC to 2015 Release when the final version is released, (without reinstallation)? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152154/can-i-update-visual-studio-community-2015-rc-to-2015-release-when-the-final-vers)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just did this today - I installed the RTM version of Visual Studio Community 2015.

All I had to do was download the installer file and it went through and updated everything to the RTM version. The only issue I had was missing Intellisense, so I had to close Visual Studio and run the `ResetUserData` flag. After I did that, Intellisense started working again.

Full Command (Start -> Run): `devenv.exe /ResetUserData`

This doesn't open VS, but it cleared the data and I was able to restart...a few compatibility checker errors popped up, but I'm back running. Customization are gone, but for me it's not a big deal to start fresh.

**Update:** For those also using ReSharper, I had to upgrade to the latest version (from 9.0 to 9.0 update 1) get it fully working. I ended up disabling it though as performance was suffering greatly. I will try investigating further later.

**Update 2:** I directed my coworker to update to the latest version, he received an error that he had a pre-release version of VS Web Express. We uninstalled the web express and we were able to continue.

**Update 3:** I'm no longer having any issues. I believe ReSharper pushed out another update and everything seems fairly smooth. ReSharper Version 9.1.3. There might be a few things here and there, but nothing that has been cause for me to regret upgrading. Pretty typical stuff. So far the reward has outweighed the risk. +1 to upgrade to VS 2015.

I've done this upgrade on <strike>two of my machines with no issues</strike> two of my own machines, and directed two other acquaintances to upgrade as well.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I hesitated to simply install the rtm version because I didn't want to end up with 2 instances of vs, but everything worked fine. UPD: I've also encountered the issue with IntelliSence and the specified command has helped me.

Comment: I have tried this, but after installation, it still says I have the RC version. I tried a clean install on a second machine, and it turned out to be the RC version too. Does anyone have a link to the RTM download?

Comment: Or is the display in the about dialog just wrong? It shows 'Version 14.0.25424.00 Update 3'

Answer (score 4):

If you're actively developing an UWP, you might want to wait:

http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/29/release-dates-and-compatibility-visual-studio-2015-and-windows-10-sdk/

Otherwise, you should be able to dl the web installer and have it upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I used the ISO to install VS 2015 CE RTM on my Win 10 Build 10240 system where VS 2015 CE RC was already installed.
Everything installed/updated with no issues (so far) in limited testing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to uninstall RC and then install RTM. The Web Installer refuses to install due to the presence of the pre-release version on the machine. At least it does for me.

Comment: Really? It didn't for me and that is why I am having problems now I am afraid. Some packages are not loading. Bummed out right now!

Answer (score 0):

After several hours, it put up a menu requiring me to restart and remove the previous version of C++ 2015 Redistributable x64 and x86.  Apparently, it might be better to remove these before starting the upgrade.
I hesitated to perform the upgrade due to the confirmed reports that Intel C++ will not necessarily work with -std=c++11 or c++14 and vs2015u2 until the future update 16.0.3 is available.  I have confirmed with a test installation that I had no such problem in the absence of c++11 or c++14 option usage.