# Visual Studio doesn't like the arity of my program and I don't like its general arity

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Okay, sorry for the jocular title.

My Visual Studio Community 2015 RC installation has stopped opening my solution. It first displayed error message boxes notifying me of its inability to load certain packages such as the `ErrorListPackage` (the name give its function) and the `C# Parser` or some such package and now when I try to close it because it hasn't loaded my solution at all and the Solution Explorer is completely empty, it displays this strange error message.

[image]

If I try to open a new project of any kind, I get this error message box.

[image]

All this started after the last Windows update I applied on my machine last night.

Comment: Maybe too extreme of a solution, but could you try upgrading to VS RTM?

Comment: @Banex: I am going to have to do that, it looks like. Roughly how long does that take? Do I have to uninstall this one first?

Comment: You'd be more safe uninstalling the RC one first and restarting your pc. On my old dual core it took no more than 40mins (also including C++ toolset).

Comment: @Banex: Thank you. I couldn't agree more with you. But someone just pointed out to me on this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/q/31985638/303685) another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/q/31527901/303685) that said that I could just upgrade it and it would work all nice and fine.

Comment: I will try the upgrade first and then if it still misbehaves (hoping not), I'll uninstall all of it and do a fresh install.

Comment: @Banex: I am having second thoughts reading mixed reviews on that thread. I'll do what you said. Uninstall RC and install RTM. Best and safest.

Comment: I suggested upgrading also because Visual Studio RTM is meant for production while RC was still, as the name implies, a "candidate".