# Do I have to uninstall Visual Studio Community 2015 RC before I can install Visual Studio Community 2015 RTM?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Do I have to uninstall Visual Studio Community 2015 RC before I can install Visual Studio Community 2015 RTM or would it just understand and upgrade itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upgrade Visual Studio 2015 RC to RTM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527901/how-to-upgrade-visual-studio-2015-rc-to-rtm)

Answer (score 0):

In my replacement of 2015u1 by 2015u2 RTM, it was required to restart and use add/remove menu to remove the previous versions of C++ 2015 Redistributable x64 and x86.